# Fetch values from an xml file and write into a excel sheet row-wise

Tags: c#, .net, xml, excel, xpath

I have a situation here, I have to write a simple WPF apps with a textbox and a button, textbox is for "en", "fr", "ru", etc...

I have a lot of files with huge number of data like this. Consider this is a file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<params>
    <btestsir xml:lang="fr" tId="HHXAF">Test Sirène :</btestsir>
    <btestsir xml:lang="en" tId="HHXAF">Test Siren :</btestsir>
    <btestsir xml:lang="pt" tId="HHXAF">Testar sirene:</btestsir>
    <btestsir xml:lang="ru" tId="HHXAF">Тест сирены:</btestsir>

    <btestbeep xml:lang="fr" tId="HHXA2">Test Bip :</btestbeep>
    <btestbeep xml:lang="en" tId="HHXA2">Test Beep :</btestbeep>
    <btestbeep xml:lang="pt" tId="HHXA2">Testar aviso sonoro:</btestbeep>
    <btestbeep xml:lang="ru" tId="HHXA2">Тест гудка:</btestbeep>
</params>
```

Now if I select "en" through my application,  and click on the button then only two strings whose xml:lang="en" values match will be copied to an excel sheet. and would display something like this.

```
For English language
```

[image]

```
For Russian language
```

[image]

I have tried this

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(strFilepath);
string line;
while(null != (line = reader.ReadLine()))
   {                  
       string[] s1 = line.Split('>');
       string[] s2 = s1[1].Split('<');

       if(s1[0].Contains("xml:lang="))
       {

       }
   }
```

Logic behind this is simple first I want to split every line using ">" 
So `s1[0]` will have `<btestsir xml:lang="fr" transId="HHXAF"`
`s1[1]` will have  `Test Sirène :</btestsir>`

But here the problem I am facing is how to fetch the "key" for a specific language `xml:lang=` and put that key-value pair to excel sheet, As I have shown in the picture. Fetching the "value" is easy `s2[0]` will have the `value`.

But this two key-value pair should be match and then put into the excel sheet, then it will again continue for the next line. 
Edit: One point here the key value pair should be put into different excel-sheet for different language files. excel-sheet.en.xlsx will  contain all "en", excel-sheet.fr.xlsx will  contain all "fr",  etc

As I said I have huge files and it should work seamlessly without manual intervention.

Can you help me please!

Thanks

Comment: They way you are doing is not ideal. You should rather be working properly with XML.

Comment: I know that, but I also know this code is 2002 code and I cannot do better than that, btw its not an XML file, it may look like though. Moreover to get the ideal solution I have come up here.

Answer (score 2):

I would use xpath selectors and not try string manipulation of an xml file. So you could do something like declare a nodelist variable and populate it ie:
using System.xml;
...
   XmlNodeList childNodes;

childNodes = xml.SelectNodes("ParentNodeofbtestsirNode/btestsirnode[@lang='en']);
...
and go on from there doing your manipulations against each XmlNode such as
foreach(XmlNode xnd in childNodes)
{
 '...
}

Comment: But the main question is how to put those key value pair to excelsheet row by row, fetching values my code is also doing, may be not the efficient way but those values shoudl be put into the different excelsheet for different langauge

Comment: Are you now writing to a new excel file and you are just wondering how to create/select sheets or do you have an existing file already that maybe you are appending to?

Comment: yes i am creating a new file for each language and then i am appending the values row wise in the excel sheet for that particular language, please i have updated my question

Comment: Then create a new sheet for each language, say the two character code you are using like "fr" and "en" and then when you have that value in s2[0] use it to select your sheet. Then find the next empty row and append it there. Use something like    dim lastRow as integer    lastRow = Worksheets("fr").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

Comment: i have updated the xml file, can you please provide more details, as `"ParentNodeofbtestsirNode/btestsirnode[` is confusing to me, its huge file, I cannot change this string as this nodes keep getting changed after r repetitions, it every time changes to new node. So this node value and innertext of this node it has to fetch based upon the `lang='en'` can you help me.

Comment: ok, the ParentNode thing is just a placeholder for well-formed xml. You indicated that this file, though it looks like XML, is not really an xml file. You can possibly turn it into one by adding a parent node and call it whatever. Then you would be able to populate a nodelist like I and Yahya showed you. That is why you would use the "ParentNode/btestsirnode[" syntax. Do you think you can make the file into an xml? You might have to do a little research on it but even in .net 2.0 will handle xml. Anyways, is the problem you are having to obtain the data or to manipulate excel once you have it?

Comment: Just a question, have you tried importing the data directly into excel? From there you could just write a macro that would put the data where you want it and it might be easier that way. It really depends on your situation though.

Comment: Yes I tried importing to excel, but unfortunately its not a XML file, u guessed it right.And that's the reason I have to find a work around of how to solve it. I replied to Yahya that its not XML file. Using my approach I have found the solution but that's not the optimal approach. Anyways thanks for the input and your precious time. Really appreciates.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do it:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("sample.xml");
var root = doc.DocumentElement;
var elements = root.XPathSelectElements("//[@xml:lang='en']");


foreach (var child in elements) 
{

 //child.Name >> will give you btestsir
 //child.Value >> will give you Test Siren :
}
```

And to create/manage spreadsheets use EPPlus [see sample here](http://tedgustaf.com/blog/2012/11/create-excel-20072010-spreadsheets-with-c-and-epplus/)

Comment: But the main question is how to put those key value pair to excelsheet row by row

Comment: @Debhere I have added a link to my answer to EPPLus sample. Unfortunately nobody can hold your hand and walk through exact solution. This is a Q&A site.